# Writing to a worksheet from a VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, subroutine

I am trying to write some intermediate results in a user defined VBA function to a worksheet. I have tested the function, and it works correctly. I am aware that I cannot modify / write to cells from a UDF, so I tried passing the relevant results to a subroutine which I hoped would then be able to write to the spreadsheet.

Unfortunately my scheme doesn't work, and I am trying to think through this problem.

```
Public Function f(param1, param2)
    result = param1 * param2
    call writeToSheet(result)
    f = param1 + param2
end

public sub writeToSheet(x)
    dim c as range
    c = range("A1")
    c.value = x
end
```

I would like to see  the product of param1 and param2 in cell A1. Unfortunately, it does not happen - the subroutine just ends abruptly as soon as it attempts to execute the first statement (c = range("A1") ). What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

If it is simply impossible to write to a spreadsheet in this way, is there some other way in which to store intermediate results for later review? My real life problem is a little more complicated that my stylized version above, as I generate a new set of intermediate results each time I go through a loop, and want to store them all for review.

Comment: `Set c = Range("A1")`.

Comment: You could always write to the Immediate window, or to a global array (which you could read later)

Comment: Consider running your analysis FROM a subroutine instead of driving it from the worksheet. Functions work just fine that way. It is only when you call them from cell formulas that you have the limitation... by design.

Comment: If you wanted a less volatile alternative, instead of writing to a sheet, perhaps write the data to a text file. You could even setup an application.ontime call to a procedure which loads the data from the text file into a cell (or range).

Comment: Store the UDF results in global dictionary, and output them in AfterCalculation event, which fires after all UDFs are processed, that is why you can output in any cell without violation.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Set c=Range("A1") is indeed the correct syntax, though it does not resolve the problem, which is intrinsic to UDFs. The others I was unaware of (in particular storing the results in a global dictionary - will look this up and if I can't get it to work, I may come back for some additional assistance), The quick and dirty solution appears to be to write to the Immediate Window, and that's my first step. Thanks as always - you've been an immense help.

Comment: May I follow up the debug.print solution? I want to print 5 numbers, preferably on a single line at each loop iteration. I create an array
            dummy(1) = slope1
            dummy(1) = intercept1
            dummy(3) = slope2
            dummy(4) = intercept2
            dummy(5) = sse(i)

and then try and print it using
debug.print Join(dummy, "',"), 
but this fails. I have no problem printing it in a loop
for d=1 to 5
    debug.print dummy(d)
next d

but this then leaves me with a long list of numbers. Is there a clean way in which to print all 5 numbers on one line?

Answer (score 1):

This idea might work for you. The function `ParamProduct` calls `SetProps` which writes both parameters to custom document properties (View from *File > Properties > Advanced Properties > Custom*). Call the function with `=ParamProduct(A1, A2)` or `=ParamProduct(123, 321)`

```
Function ParamProduct(Param1 As Variant, _
                      Param2 As Variant) As Double

    Dim Fun As Double
    Dim Param As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Param = Param1
    For i = 1 To 2
        SetProp "Param" & i, Param
        Param = Param2
    Next i
    ParamProduct = Param1 + Param2
End Function

Private Sub SetProp(Pname As String, _
                    PropVal As Variant)
    ' assign PropVal to document Property(Pname)
    ' create a custom property if it doesn't exist

    Dim Pp As DocumentProperty
    Dim Typ As MsoDocProperties

    If IsNumeric(PropVal) Then
        Typ = msoPropertyTypeNumber
    Else
        Select Case VarType(PropVal)
            Case vbDate
                Typ = msoPropertyTypeDate
            Case vbBoolean
                Typ = msoPropertyTypeBoolean
            Case Else
                Typ = msoPropertyTypeString
        End Select
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Pp = .CustomDocumentProperties(Pname)

        If Err.Number Then
            .CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:=Pname, LinkToContent:=False, _
                                          Type:=Typ, Value:=PropVal
        Else
            With Pp
                If .Type <> Typ Then .Type = Typ
                .Value = PropVal
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Use this UDF to recall the properties to the worksheet.

```
Function GetParam(ByVal Param As String) As Variant
    GetParam = Propty(Param)
End Function

Private Function Propty(Pname As String) As Variant
    ' SSY 050 ++
    ' return null string if property doesn't exist

    Dim Fun As Variant
    Dim Pp As DocumentProperty

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Pp = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties(Pname)

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Select Case Pp.Type
            Case msoPropertyTypeNumber
                Fun = CLng(Fun)
            Case msoPropertyTypeDate
                Fun = CDate(Fun)
            Case msoPropertyTypeBoolean
                Fun = CBool(Fun)
            Case Else
                Fun = CStr(Fun)
        End Select
        Fun = Pp.Value
    End If
```

The worksheet function below works (A6 has a value of "Param2")
`=GetParam("Param1")*GetParam(A6)`

The above code will create a property if it doesn't exist or change its value if it does. The sub below will delete an existing property and do nothing if it's called to delete a property that doesn't exist. You might call it from one of the above subs or functions.

```
Private Sub DelProp(ByVal Pname As String)

    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties(Pname).Delete
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a mill. I went with the debug.print idea, and created a single string with 5 numbers and then printed it.

dummystr = CStr(slope1) & ", " & CStr(intercept1) & ", " & CStr(slope2) & ", " & CStr(intercept2) & ", " & CStr(sse(i))
            Debug.Print dummystr

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Using properties you could bring either the string as a whole or each component separately back into Excel. If you add `Application.Volatile` to the UDF it will be in real time, as if the UDF had, in fact, written to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a mill everyone. Printing to the immediate window is the easiest by far, but allowed me to print only a single item. I therefore concatenated all 5 items into a single string and printed it in the immediate window:

dummystr = CStr(slope1) & ", " & CStr(intercept1) & ", " & CStr(slope2) & ", " & CStr(intercept2) & ", " & CStr(sse(i))
Debug.Print dummystr